# How can I test $watch in Angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test `$scope.$watch` in controller, I don't know why `$scope.$apply()` in test code causes unexpected request error such as  `Error: Unexpected request: GET /locales/en.json`. That's other part of the controller, why it's involved here?

However this error will not occur if I comment `$scope.$apply`, but of course $watch cannot be triggered in that case. Do I have to mock those requests like `$httpBackend.whenGET('/locales/en.json').respond('');` ?

controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){

    return $location.path();

    }, function() {

    $scope.currentPath = $location.path().match(/\/[a-z0-9A-Z_]*/)[0];

    $scope.currentNav = 'menu.' + $scope.currentPath.replace('/', '');

});
```

jasmine:

```
describe('homeController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('homeApp'));

    var $rootScope, $scope, controller, $httpBackend, $location, $route, $window

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$location_, _$route_, _$window_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('homeController', {$scope: $scope});
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $location = _$location_;
        $route = _$route_;
        $window = _$window_;
    }));

    describe('watch path', function() {

        it('should change currentPath and currentNav', function() {
            $location.path('/dashboard');
            $scope.$apply();

            $location.path('/images');
            $scope.$apply();

            expect($scope.currentPath).toBe('/images')
            expect($scope.currentNav).toBe('menu.images')
        })
    })
})
```

---

**update**:

It's working after mocking all the http requests required. But still want to know why it affects those requests.

Comment: as `$scope.watch` expects parameter that call `$scope.apply` here is your $scope.watch causing problem

Answer (score -1):

In above example you are not watching anything. $watch function will be called when value of object being watched changes. It will return you both old and new value for object.

```
$scope.someValue = 0;

  $scope.$watch(
    "$scope.someValue",
    function handleFooChange(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log("$scope.someValue:", newValue);
    }
  );
```

Here someValue is being watched for change. Once value of someValue will change, callback function of $watch will be called.